# Pgsql Delete rows with some columns (not all) duplicate

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table - col_pk, col1, col2,col3, col4, col_date_updated

This table has some rows with duplicate column values for col2 and col3. 
I want to keep those rows with col_date_updated is latest(max).

Eg:

```
col_pk, col1, col2,  col3, col4,   col_date_updated
1,      A,    hello, now,  200.00, 2017-12-12 15:09:44.437546
2,      B,    hello, now,  490.00, 2017-12-12 15:09:42.437065
3,      C,    hi,    now,  300.00, 2017-12-12 15:09:41.436617
4,      D,    hello, now,  250.00, 2017-12-12 15:09:45.436617
5,      E,    hi,    now,  250.00, 2017-12-12 10:09:41.436617
```

Expected Result:

```
col_pk, col1, col2,  col3, col4,   col_date_updated
3,      C,    hi,    now,  300.00, 2017-12-12 15:09:41.436617
4,      D,    hello, now,  250.00, 2017-12-12 15:09:45.436617
```

Comment: Do you want a query returning that result, or do you want to permanently delete (remove) those rows from the table?

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col2, col3) t.*
FROM table t
ORDER BY col_date_updated DESC
```

apply distinct on col2 and col3 cause you want them unique and keep the latest with order by desc

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *select* to get your expected output, then `ROW_NUMBER` comes in handy:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3
        ORDER BY col_date_updated DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT col_pk, col1, col2,  col3, col4, col_date_updated
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you instead want to delete the other records, then we can also reuse the CTE:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE col_pk IN (SELECT col_pk FROM cte WHERE rn > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM yourtable t
 WHERE col_date_updated IN (SELECT MAX (col_date_updated)
                    FROM yourtable i
                   WHERE t.col2 = i.col2 AND t.col3 = i.col3);
```

So, If you wish to delete other records, you may use this.

```
DELETE 
  FROM yourtable t
 WHERE col_date_updated NOT IN (SELECT MAX (col_date_updated)
                    FROM yourtable i
                   WHERE t.col2 = i.col2 AND t.col3 = i.col3);
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/57988/6)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress all but the most recent rows for any {col2,col3}:

---

```
SELECT *
FROM thetable zt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        -- If a record exists with the same col2,col3,
        -- but a more recent date than zt.col_date_updated
        -- then zt.* cannot be the most recent one
        SELECT *
        FROM thetable nx
        WHERE nx.col2 = zt.col2 -- same value
        AND nx.col3 = zt.col3   -- same value
        AND nx.col_date_updated > zt.col_date_updated -- more recent
        );
```

---

If you want to physically delete all but the most recent rows for the same {col2,col3}:

---

```
DELETE
FROM thetable zt
WHERE EXISTS (
        -- If a record exists with the same col2,col3,
        -- but a more recent date than zt.t.col_date_updated
        -- then zt.* cannot be the most recent one
        -- and we can delete zt.
        SELECT *
        FROM thetable nx
        WHERE nx.col2 = zt.col2 -- same value
        AND nx.col3 = zt.col3   -- same value
        AND nx.col_date_updated > zt.col_date_updated -- more recent
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

This is fastest way:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE col_pk IN 
       (SELECT col_pk FROM 
               (SELECT col_pk, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY col2, col3 ORDER BY col_date_updated) AS rnum
        FROM tablename) t
 WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

---

if you want delete:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE col_pk IN 
       (SELECT col_pk FROM 
               (SELECT col_pk, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY col2, col3 ORDER BY col_date_updated) AS rnum
        FROM tablename DESC) t
 WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```